# Ag-Grid Unbalanced Groups - How can I move ungrouped rows to the bottom of grid

Tags: ag-grid

For unbalanced groups in Ag-Grid, how can I move all ungrouped rows to the bottom of the grid?

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/27.0.0/react-data-grid/grouping-unbalanced-groups/

[image: 1]

after I added new empty row, it always shows at the top of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using the `initialGroupOrderComparator` property.

```
initialGroupOrderComparator={(parmas) => {
  const { nodeA, nodeB } = parmas;
  if (nodeA.group && !nodeB.group) {
    return -1;
  else if (!nodeA.group && nodeB.group) {
     return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}}
```